# How to change the direction of c# polar chart clockwise to counterclockwise?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, charts

I've been trying to change the direction of the polar chart component Visual Studio 2010 (C#).
By default the chart is displayed in clockwise orientation. I need to change this to counterclockwise orientation. What property do I use in the chart to do this.

Comment: This never came to pass; [MS recommends using CustomLabels](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/263f4d75-e294-4f28-a75f-032f5e130a57/display-circular-scale-in-polar-chart-anticlockwise?forum=MSWinWebChart).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there´s no such feature in polar mscharts.I only found a workaround for this question. The way to do counterclockwise plotting is by reversing yourself all the labels(ex. 30 -> 330; 60->300; 90->270..etc)and your data also.